# How can I amend a string which will then update a link when appended with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like a user to be able to amend a string (in case it is incorrect) which has itself been injected from a url parameter and then update a link with the same parameter whether it has been updated or not.

```
<p id="para" contenteditable="true">Placeholder text</p>
<a href="url" class=append">link text</a>
```

So, I've got the parameter from the url.

```
var parameter_value = gup('parameter');
```

Replaced the placeholder text if the parameter is empty.

```
if(parameter_value!== '') {
    $("#para").html(parameter_value);
}
```

This changes the value of the injected string sourced from the url parameter.

```
$('#para').on('focus', function() {
    before = $(this).html();
}).on('blur keyup paste', function() { 
    if (before != $(this).html()) {
        $(this).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

And this appends the parameter & value to the link.

```
$('a.append').attr('href', function() {
    return this.href + '&' + 'parameter=' + parameter_value;
}
```

If the parameter value is amended by a user, I can't get the amended value into the final append.

It will appear changed in the console.log if I put that after 'trigger', so from my basic understanding of jQuery, I believe it's a scope thing, but I don't know how to get it to update parameter_value to be appended to the link.

Another question I have, after looking around for the answer is. Is this a reasonable way of doing this or is there a better way?

Here's a quick fiddle of the basics: http://jsfiddle.net/DrMadvibe/U9LFW/

Answer (score 0):

is the string that the user is editing in an input field?

If so something like:

```
$('.field').on('blur', function(e) {
 yourAppendMethod($(this).val());
});

function yourAppendMethod (newString) {
  $('a.append').attr('href', function() {
    return this.href + '&' + 'parameter=' + parameter_value + newString;  //or however you want to implement.
  }
}
```

Comment: No it isn't. It's just a legacy p tag to which I added contenteditable=true. We've a got a few similar pages, but this functionality  is a new request, so I wondered if this would work rather than monkeying around with forms. The parameter_value needs to be updated with whatever the user enters: it's not a new string.